# unzip files from and to different directories

Tags: bash, unzip

I have a folder structure akin to the below:

```
├── scripts
│   ├── unzipper.sh
├── zips
│   ├── foo_bar.zip
│   ├── qux.zip
│   └── foo_baz.zip
└── unzipped
```

From the unzipped folder, I'm aiming to run the unzipper.sh script to unzip the files in the zips directory to the unzipped folder (the current working directory). I'd like to end up with:

```
├── scripts
│   ├── unzipper.sh
├── zips
│   ├── foo_bar.zip
│   ├── qux.zip
│   └── foo_baz.zip
└── unzipped
    ├── foo_bar
    ├─── somefile.txt
    ├── qux
    ├─── another.txt
    ├── foo_baz
    └─── moar.txt
```

The unzipper.sh script, currently, contains the following:

```
for i in *.zip; do unzip "$i" -d "${i%%.zip}"; done
```

This works great for unzipping files that are in the current working directory to the current working directory, but I'm struggling to work out the right syntax to reference a zip in a different folder to unzip it to the current directory.

Appreciate it's probably a simple fix, but I'm missing the obvious here.

Comment: I don't know if this will work *Right away,  but  hopefully I can contribute to something:  `find Directory/ -name "*.zip" -type f -exec unzip {} {}.zip \;`  I haven't tried this, but it can 'point' to the (hopefully) correct path

Comment: Why can't you use `for i in ../zips/*.zip; do unzip "$i" -d "../unzipped/${i%%.zip}"; done`?

Comment: that unzips a file from `../zips/foo_bar.zip` to `../unzipped/../zips/foo_bar`

Comment: `for i in ../zips/*.zip; do unzip "$i" -d "$(basename "$i" .zip)"; done`

Comment: perfect! that works. I never knew about the `basename` element.